# Possible to have Twitter's Typeahead plugin initially slide down or fadeIn?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter, typeahead.js

Anyone know of a fairly simple way to get the dropdown from Twitter's typeahead jQuery plugin to initially slideDown or fadeIn. I am trying to get the size of the dropdown menu to animate when the size is adjusted, but I would settle for at least a fade or an initial slide in. I don't want to have to modify the actual plugin itself.

Typeahead plugin and demos can be found here: https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to or can't edit the plugin file, the solution is more convoluted than it should be. They provide a [`typeahead:opened` event](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js#custom-events); however, for the purposes of fading, it does not trigger in some cases where it needs to. Thus, you'll basically need to attach event listeners to the user interface events that would trigger and untrigger the dropdown.

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Handle dropdown fade-in
    $('.typeahead').bind("keydown mousedown focus",function(){
        if (!$(".tt-dropdown-menu").is(":visible")) {
            $(".tt-dropdown-menu").stop(true).hide().fadeIn();
        }
    });
    // Handle dropdown fade-out
    $('.typeahead').on("typeahead:closed",function(){
        $(".tt-dropdown-menu").stop(true).show().fadeOut();
    });
});
```

### Note: Replace the `.typeahead` selector with whatever your input is.

---

If you have the ability to edit the plugin itself, all you have to do is replace the following strings with their counterparts to get `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` to work.

**Non-Minimized Version (typeahead.js):**

1. Replace `this.$menu.css("display", "block");` with `this.$menu.stop(true).fadeIn();`
2. Replace `this.$menu.hide();` with `this.$menu.stop(true).fadeOut();`

**Minimized Version (typeahead.min.js):**

1. Replace `this.$menu.css("display","block")` with `this.$menu.stop(true).fadeIn()`
2. Replace `this.$menu.hide()` with `this.$menu.stop(true).fadeOut()`

---

*Note: Tested in version 0.9.3 of typeahead.js only, using Chrome*

Comment: Problem with typeahead:opened isn't that it isn't firing, actually it's firing prematurely moment input is focused even when there are no datums to show which is rather stupid. This has to be a bug.

Comment: Correct, it does trigger. As I mentioned, it just doesn't trigger in cases that it needs to for the purpose of getting a fade-in / fade-out effect working. This isn't necessarily a bug.

Comment: Awesome! I appreciate your response! I have no problem editing the file, but the client wants to keep the script hosted from a CDN, but the client does not want to pay for a CDN, so we are using the script hosted from cloudflare, otherwise I would just edit the file. Thanks for your time and effort!